# TightVNCserver issue

Tags: vnc

Has anyone run into

input: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24
output:
            Warning: raspberrypi:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X1-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server raspberrypi:1? when installing tightvncserver.

side-note : I have to use vnc I guess because Quartz X11 forwarding is an extra download on my el Capital OSX.

Comment: Why `vncserver :1` ? Obviously this is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try x11vnc as an alternative